# When i trigger cloudcustodian policy with sns service the SNS mail message delivering in unreadable format

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-ses, cloudcustodian

When I trigger custodian policy with sns service, message is delivering in an unreadable format.

`default.html` from `c7n-mailer`

```
policies:
  - name: policyname-groups
    resource: security-group
    description: |
      Remove any rule from a security group that allows open ports ingress
      and notify the user who added the violating rule.
    filters:
     - type: ingress
       Cidr:
        value_type: cidr
        op: eq
        value: "0.0.0.0/0"
    mode:
       role: arn:aws:iam::92*****:role/Custodian
       schedule: 'cron(00/10 14 * * ? *)'
       type: periodic
    actions:
     - type: notify
       template: default.html
       priority_header: 1
       subject: " Created-[custodian {{ account }} - {{ region }}]"
       violation_desc: |
         " Which Had Rules Open To The World:"
       action_desc: |
         "taken"
         "Taken: The Violating Security Group Rule Needs to be Removed As It
         Violates Our Company's Cloud Policy. Please Refer To The Cloud FAQ."
       to:
         - mailid@domain.com
       transport:
         type: sns
         region: regionname
         topic: topicname
```

Answer (score 0):

c7n-mailer is used to actually deliver, lookup addresses, and format messages for delivery.

https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/tools/c7n-mailer.html